# Date Calculation for Leave Entitlement

Tags: calculated-column, date

I am trying to calculate leave entitlement based on the date of joining and current date, at antry date the person has 20 days of leave if the person has completed their 2nd year anniversary by 01 April then they would get 4 extra days.

E.G.

- if joining date is 15/03/18 annual leave = 24 (completed 2 years by 01 April of current year 2020)
- if joining date is 15/06/18 annual leave = 20 (has not completed 2 full yeas by 01 April of current year 2020)

I have he excel formula which works perfectly:

```
=20+(EDATE(A2,24)<=DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),4,1))*4
```

I have been trying to apply the same principal on a calculated column in a SharePoint Library Where I had a **Joining Date** and a **Leave** column; I have twicked the code below but it does not work

```
=20+(DATE([Joining Date])<=DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),4,1))*4
```

Any ideas on how I can solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below and let me know if that meets your requirements

```
=IF(DATEDIF(JoiningDate,DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),4,1),"d")>=(365*2),24,20)
```

[image]

Comment: Apologies I had to abandon the project, and just restarting this now. I have used the formula but it appears not to work, example if I enter 20/03/19 it returns 24 as of today 13/02/21, it should return 20 as 2 years anniversary will be 01/04/21

Comment: The Date on April 1 of the current year is 01/04/2021 and the joining date is 20/03/2019. Days between these two dates are 743 which is greater than 365x2=730 days, hence 24 days. If you're working with different logic, let me know

Comment: Apologies, the entitlement to 24 days only triggers if they have completed 2 full years by 1st April.

Comment: E.G. JoiningDate = 31/03/19 and Today(16/02/21) they will have 20 days however one reaching Today(01/04/21), they will have 24 days, however if your JoiningDate in 05/04/19 then on Today(01/04/21) they will still be on 20 days as they have not completed 2 full years by then, hope this makes sense

Comment: Then you will just need this ````=IF(DATEDIF(JoiningDate,TODAY(),"d")>=(365*2),24,20)````. For this kind of formula where TODAY() is involved, you need to run a workflow every day to calculate Days as **Calculated** columns don't get updated automatically